# share annotaion validation rules between form and persistence

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2

one "simple" question: http://mwop.net/blog/2012-07-02-zf2-beta5-forms.html

is it possible to use the zf2 zend form annotation validation rules without using zend form, so i can share the validation rules between a model validator (e.g. using for check if the model is correct before persisting it) and the zend form validation?

if my "name" should be not empty and between 5 and 20 characters, it is the same rule for the form and the model.

i hope i pointed it out clearly

Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since all data that the models are getting would be from user input or the database, you shouldn't need to test the models itself, too. THe data inside the database should be correct!

IE: trust your own data but not the users?

But if you still wanna do that, i guess you could build the form with the AnnotationBuilder, then get the InputFilters from the Form (im sure there's a method, maybe on per-element-basis) and then use those inside your models - but as my first paragraph implies, i see this as a quite useless point :)

As for multi usable input filters, best thing would be to write own classes extending [Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html) on a per model basis. When you build your form then you can attach that class as the filter definition via `$form->setInputFilter($myModelInputFilterClass)` and you could also call that class inside your models to run your data through those filters. I haven't done this manually but it should work.

The only pitfall i guess might happen if you run into required statements. Checking on a per element basis, i don't know if that will work, too. As the InputFilter checks against all given filters. Though if you import a full CSV-Sheet or something you'd have a `populateFromCsv()` function or something that then checks all data anyways i guess.

Comment: it's about validating data coming from...let's say csv-files. using a "form" object felt wrong - but - if it is doing the right thing...why not

Comment: well didn't think of csv data, but i guess the 2nd approach could work. Other than that, if you define the filter separately i.e. class extending InputFilter instead of the Annotations, then it could work more easily.

Comment: so, that's getting near to what i need - is there a way to have a validator class, that can be used with zend_form and as "stand-alone" validator? that's exactly what i need

Comment: Slightly added my answer to give you some more insight. Check the documentation for Zend\Form, too, or rather the introduction, it may clear things up even further for you.

Comment: oh great, i didn't take care about Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter for validating my model, this is exactly what i'm looking for! Great, thanks!